# AngularJS checkbox issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to angularjs and I'm working on an app. I'm having problems with a checkbox. Selecting the checkboxes outputs the correct array elements, but the problem is when I unselect them. The elements just add themselves back into the array. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself... I think what needs to happen is to remove the selected checkbox from array if it's unchecked. Have I missed a loop somewhere or would I need add a $watch?. I've been trying to solve this for hours now! 
Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
Here is the code:

HTML: This is the select/unselect on table header.

 <td class="checkbox-selector">
                                Select All
                                <input type="checkbox"  
                                       ng-model="selectedAll" 
                                       ng-click="checkAll()">
                            </td>

    ..and the individual checkboxes:



<td>
                            <input type="checkbox" 
                                   class="checkbox-row"
                                   ng-model="result.isSelected"
                                   ng-click="selectedShop(result.shopName, result.ItemId)" />
                            </td>

Angularjs:

 $scope.allSelection = [];

    $scope.checkAll = function() {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        }       
        angular.forEach($scope.results, function (result) {  
            result.isSelected = $scope.selectedAll;  
            $scope.allSelection.push("result.shopName"+"result.itemId");        

            $scope.allSelection=[];

        });
    };


$scope.selection=[];

$scope.selectedShop = function selectedShop(shopName, itemId) {
     $scope.selection.push("shopName"+ "itemId");

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks fairly simple to be solved by debugging `#checkAll` function.

But at a glance, it looks like there's a mistake in iteration part of `#checkAll` -- I *think* your intention is to cleanup allSelection first (outside forEach), and then conditionally add all items (if selected).

Something like this:

```
$scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.selectedAll = !$scope.selectedAll;
    $scope.allSelection=[];
    angular.forEach($scope.results, function (result) {  
        result.isSelected = $scope.selectedAll;  
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.allSelection.push(/*whatever needs to be in that array*/);        
        }
    });
}
```

Another advice is extracting the part that doesn't work properly (and possibly sharing on JSFiddle).

Comment: Hi Arturs, I think you have solved my problem - by clearing up the allSelection. I thought that had to be at the end... I will share on JSFiddle if I come across more problems, I 'm sure I will.. A million thanks for your help, really appreciate it :)!!